# Algorithm for finding and printing all cycles of length m in undirected, possibly unconnected graph with n vertices?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, cycle

I’m looking for an efficient algorithm to find all cycles of length m in an undirected, possibly unconnected graph with n nodes.

A fine start is here ( https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-the-cycles-in-an-undirected-graph/ ), but I would like to limit the search and output to cycles of a specified length.

The input graph is likely to be very large (n=10000’s of nodes); my initial requirement is to find all cycles of length m=5.

Suggestions?

Comment: Find all cycles then filter that list for cycles of length `m`. The search algorithm is a DFS so trying to meet the limit within the search doesn't buy you much.

Comment: Sadly, I feared that filtering after finding all cycles would end up being the way to go. C’est la math.